# Subsetting a data frame with column values from another data frame in R

Tags: r, subset

I wanted to subset `DataframeB` if the row names could be find in the `DataframeA$GENE_NAME`.  The insides of the two Dataframe look like:

```
> head(DataframeA,n=5)
      GENE_NAME REFSEQ_ID       PROXIMAL_ENHANCERS ENHANCER_RANKS IS_SUPER
1        Mir715 NR_030494  chr17:39979923-39985799              3        1
2       Fam118b NM_194257   chr9:35112749-35113239              5        1
3        Rpusd4 NM_028040   chr9:35112749-35113239              5        1
4          Mid1 NM_183151 chrX:166423967-166446961              6        1
5 G530011O06Rik NR_029457 chrX:166423967-166446961              6        1
> head(DataframeB, n=5)
               baseMean log2FoldChange     lfcSE      stat       pvalue
0610010K14Rik 271.52224     -0.7115865 0.1917668 -3.710687 0.0002066974
0610011F06Rik 212.06510      0.7205455 0.2171168  3.318700 0.0009043745
1500011B03Rik 288.32598      0.6187032 0.1926014  3.212351 0.0013165361
1700001O22Rik  13.46958      1.9938687 0.6275085  3.177437 0.0014858295
2410004P03Rik  10.72670      2.4725729 0.6687932  3.697067 0.0002181051
                    padj
0610010K14Rik 0.01132025
0610011F06Rik 0.03132753
1500011B03Rik 0.04193546
1700001O22Rik 0.04585224
2410004P03Rik 0.01159125
```

I could do basic subsetting like:

```
Subset_of_DataframeB <- subset(DataframeB, padj < 0.05)
```

Comment: It seems to be rownames instead of first column. `df.subset <- DataframeB[rownames(DataframeB) %in% DataframeA$GENE_NAME, ]`. Take care of factors if this doesn't work.

Comment: @mt1022. Yes, It worked,perfectly!  Sorry that my R knowledge (skills) is still in its infancy, " Take care of factors if this doesn't work.", could you explain a little more in case I have the problem next time?

Comment: R converts characters to factors (which was code as intergers) by default when building dataframes. see `?factor` and search for more info online.

Comment: @mt1022, I see, TKS!